# Replace sky with consistent texture and brightness

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is the original image:

[image]

I believe I see a glow at the top, so I applied a curve to see if my suspicion was right. After applying the curve:

[image]

I tried playing around with brightness and the s-curve but it doesn't achieve what I want:
[image]

How can I generate a sky with **consistent** texture and brightness in photoshop?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The photograph is very poor quality with blown out highlights which suggests over exposure. When highlights get blown out, there is no recoverable data in the that part of the image. Personally, I don't think it's fixable in the way you describe.  Replacing the sky seems the best option.

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for the welcome. You are correct, my goal is to replace the top part of the image with a uniform consistency and texture identical (or similar) to the bottom part of the sky where it's not blown out.

Comment: When I say "replacing the sky", I mean completely replacing all of the sky with another image of the sky.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to replace the sky with a photo if you shoot or purchase one which you can freely use. The old sky can be selected with the polygonal lasso and  deleted, the new one is a new background layer. A not so fine example (see NOTE1):

[image]

The case is not trivial. The new sky must be in accordance with the perspective of the original image and the colors and light conditions of the city. The perspective happens to be quite right. Fortunately the buildings cover the nearest waves which would otherwise look a tsunami. But the color doesn't fit into the foggy and dark city, no matter the contrast of the city image is lifted as much as possible. The well visible indoor and outdoor lights and colorless buildings are not at all plausible pair with full daylight blue sky & sea.

One could in theory compensate by detoriating the inserted photo. It's difficult because the photo is complex. Making it stay in accordance with itself is so complex that I skip it.

But you can synthesize your own sky. At first increase the contrast of the original image with curves. You have room to make dark areas darker.

[image]

Actually I would stop here, but the idea was to make a new sky with texture and without a bright spot in the middle of the top edge.

Continue by making a selection and delete the old sky.I used the polygonal lasso. To have some playground for the new sky I also increased the canvas size to 300%. Insert a new bottom layer for the new sky.

The new sky is synthesized by applying Filter > Render > Clouds. The colors are about the same grey as the fog just above distant buildings and a not so saturated blue:

[image]

The sky must have perspective. Edit > Transform gives it. Drag the bottom narrow and the top lower to make the clouds apparently vanish towards approximately the same direction as the roofs of the nearest buildings:

[image]

This is the result after cropping the image:

[image]

It's not plausible, it should be brighter in the top edge. It can be got by inserting a curves layer with gradient layer mask:

[image]

If one happens to work in a low cost program which has layers and layer masks, but doesn't have adjustment layers  he can fade with a gradient layer mask between 2 different contrast sky layers.

An alternative without importing a real or artificial sky implant is to stretch a zone of the existing sky to full image width. The low end contrast can be increased with a curves layer:

[image]

Unfortunately the widened stripe covers parts of highest buildings. They are copied with a selection and pasted back above the stretched sky layer.

To fade the seam at the bottom edge of the widened sky stripe there's a manually painted layer mask in the stretched sky layer. It was originally solid white. Black was sprayed to the mask with a big reduced opacity soft brush.

NOTE1: The inserted image itself is fine, but using it as the background of a grey city is not. It's a low resolution "sea and sky" sample copied from a site where photographer Paige Brown presents what he can offer.

Comment: The newest Photoshop CC has an automated sky replacement feature. Do *Edit > Sky Replacement* - there's an assortment of real sky images to choose from.

Comment: It was said already in the older answer. I tried to write something more general and available also in lower cost software like GIMP.

Comment: Sure, and also there's no reason you couldn't use real sky images in GIMP either.

Comment: A well shot photo would be much better than anything artificial, but getting one which fits needs some work and can cost money, too.. The easiest way to get one is to think it beforehand and shoot it in the same session as the buildings. Camera owners often take texture photos also without actual current need (=for the future).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this sky and go from there. Choose a new background shot or if you're using PS CC v22.0 or above, use the sky replacement tool.

[image]